# How do I clone a XML document, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

What is the best way to clone a XML document in Javascript?

I tried doing

```
var newDocument = myDocument.cloneNode(true);
```

but that just returned *null*. I also considered doing

```
var newNode = myDocument.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
```

but that is not enough for my purposes, since this way the new node has the same `ownerDocument` as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like the following to clone a XML document:

```js
var newDocument = oldDocument.implementation.createDocument(
    oldDocument.namespaceURI, //namespace to use
    null,                     //name of the root element (or for empty document)
    null                      //doctype (null for XML)
);
var newNode = newDocument.importNode(
    oldDocument.documentElement, //node to import
    true                         //clone its descendants
);
newDocument.appendChild(newNode);
```

- [createDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument) documentation
- [importNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode) documentation

Comment: Just to be more complete, how do you get the `newDocument`?