# Append external svg multiple times with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

basically I just want to append to my document.body an external SVG multiple times using D3. After some research, I found out that using `d3.xml` I can manipulate an external svg file. Indeed:

```
d3.xml("myFile.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
            var svgElement = xml.documentElement;
            document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
}
```

This is pretty straightforward. Now, for testing purposes, I want to append this svg `n` times in `n` different containers and, in order to achieve that, I'm using a for loop inside my d3 request:

```
d3.xml("myFile.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
        if (error) throw error;

        // var svgElement = xml.documentElement;
        // document.body.appendChild(svgElement);

        var n = 10;

        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var svgElement = xml.documentElement;

          var container = d3.select(document.body).append("div").attr("class", function() {
            return "container" + i;
          });
          debugger;
          document.querySelector(".container" + i).appendChild(svgElement );
        }
```

As a result, I have just 1 SVG file appended to the last div with class `container9`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/QHRYJdVUcd2Z8SSNN8jN?p=preview

Comment: Hey Gerardo, thanks for the answer. I'm purposely not using the idiomatic data().enter() methods because it's not what I need there. But maybe I'm wrong and I'm just not figuring out how to achieve the "desiderata" in that way. Also, what is the point to use ES6's let instead "var"? Isn't  forbidden to re-declare a let variable?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` And I'm not even sure what is triggering this error.

Comment: Wait a minute, you have **two** loops in the plunker, while your question has only one loop. Which one is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the useful link Gerardo. I just added a plunkr to a live example. Is someone with your expertise able to give me a suggestion? Maybe it's something about the async call I'm triggering with d3.xml?

Comment: Oh, it was a barbaric copy-paste error. Sorry for that. Corrected!

Comment: There is much more to it than just scopes and loops. You will have to import/clone the node to the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711046/how-do-i-clone-a-xml-document-in-javascript. Furthermore, you have to be sure the imported SVG does not use any IDs for its elements, because those need to be unique across the entire DOM...

Comment: This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/XnG6r/) from [*"D3js - Multiple Instances of Single External SVG File"*](/q/32909786) might be a good start.